# Why do Fermi Coordinates describe a System, where an accelerated Point moving along a time-like geodetic is at Rest?

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, geodesics

It is not yet clear to me, what Fermi coordinates really mean. They are constructed in a way, where three space-like coordinates $x'^\mu_a, a=1,2,3$ orthogonal to the time-like trajectory of an accelerated point in free fall ( $U(\tau)^\mu g_{\mu \nu}x'^{\mu}_a$ = 0 ) are used to describe events near the time-line $X^\mu(\tau)$ in the manifold by a Minkowski Metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$. But why does this new coordinate system x' describe a frame, where the falling point is momentarily at rest? From what I read this should be the case - but why? Most likely I oversee a very simple and basic fact...

Comment: What is the time coordinate in Fermi coordinates?

Comment: Isn't it just zero??

Comment: It wouldn't be a set of coordinates, if it were right?

Comment: may be proper time? Your questions show me, that I not really understood the whole thing. If it would proper time, then, indeed the point must be at rest in those coordinates. But I'm not sure...sorry for asking such stupid questions. I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By construction, the spatial directions of your Fermi coordinates are orthogonal to $U^\mu(\tau)$. This mean that in these Fermi coordinates, the four velocity of the particle, $U^\mu(\tau)$, is given by

$$U^\mu(\tau) = (f(\tau),0,0,0) $$,

this means that the particle is at rest in the new coordinates.

(By choosing the time coordinate to be $\tau$, we also get that $f(\tau)=1$.)

Comment: Suddenly this makes sense :-) What is clear for an expert might not always be clear immediately for a beginner. Now I understand much better the idea behind!